# ¿Es gramaticalmente correcto decir "Qué tristeza terminar un Tour el 'mismo' primer día"?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos

Esta tarde empezó el Tour de Francia con una contrarreloj (o [*contra reloj*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AcWrKFr)) algo peligrosa por la lluvia. Varios ciclistas cayeron y, entre ellos, Alejandro Valverde, español de Murcia, debió retirarse debido a las heridas de la caída.

Al poco de ocurrir su equipo ciclista [dijo en Twitter](https://twitter.com/Movistar_Team/status/881187615105527808):

> #TDF2017 Lamentablemente, @alejanvalverde no podrá continuar en carrera. **Qué tristeza terminar un Tour el mismo primer día**. ¡¡#VamosBala!!

Está claro lo que quieren decir: qué pena terminar la participación en el Tour el mismo día en que empezaba a disputarlo. Sería lo mismo decir:

> Qué tristeza terminar un Tour el primer día.

Pero de alguna forma ese *mismo* añade un tono de fatalidad y énfasis que interpreto, pero que a la vez me chirría gramaticalmente:

> [**mismo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=POzAgFS)
>   3. adj. U., por pleonasmo, añadido a los pronombres personales y a algunos adverbios para dar más energía a lo que se dice. *Yo mismo lo haré. Ella misma se condena. Hoy mismo lo veré. Aquí mismo te espero.*

Tal y como indica el DLE este añadido se usa en adverbios o pronombres, pero *primer día* es adjetivo. ¿Podemos afirmar entonces que la frase está mal gramaticalmente o sí puede *salvarse*?

Answer (score 5):

[Aquí](http://www.eltiempo.com/deportes/ciclismo/video-del-momento-en-el-que-alejandro-valverde-se-cae-en-el-tour-de-francia-104642) puede encontrarse el tweet en cuestión.

En Internet se pueden encontrar varios ejemplos de "el mismo primer día" (también de "el mismísimo primer día"), inclusive (o mismo) en google books.

Respecto de este uso que acabo de hacer de "mismo" como adverbio, me llama la atención no encontrar referencia alguna en el DRAE...

En relación con el adjetivo "mismo", dentro del *Capítulo 13. El adjetivo y otras clases de palabras* de la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española, encontramos, en el artículo 13.4.3e, lo siguiente:

> [...] En su empleo como marcador ENFÁTICO, admite paráfrasis con expresiones como *justamente, precisamente* o el adjetivo *propio*: *La misma naturaleza del asunto obliga a ser prudente*, pero también mediante expresiones asociadas con informaciones ESCALARES, como *hasta, incluso, en persona, nada menos que*. [...]

Si bien la Gramática habla de paráfrasis, el hecho de poder asimilar el **adjetivo** enfático "mismo" a los **adverbios** "justamente, precisamente, hasta, incluso" parecería contradictorio con el hecho de que "mismo" no está registrado como adverbio. No tengo presente ningún otro caso de un adjetivo que pueda ser reemplazado por un adverbio. Lo cierto es que "mismo" es, por su posición después del artículo, adjetivo, y que ninguna de las palabras mencionadas en la Gramática lo pueden reemplazar en esa posición (ni siquiera el adjetivo "propio"), lo que nos nos permite verificar su corrección. En cuanto a su uso (como adverbio) antes del sintagma nominal, que me suena más familiar, cambiaría el significado pues dejaría de enfatizar "primer" para enfatizar toda la oración, pero sería más fácilmente sustituible por las palabras provistas por la NGLE:

- Nunca tuvo ganas. Mismo (Inclusive) el primer día estaba desganado.

Mi humilde respuesta a la pregunta es que:

- Según la NGLE no se puede verificar su corrección porque, por su posición detrás del artículo, no sería sustituible por ninguna de las palabras provistas.
- Algunos hablantes lo usan para reforzar el adjetivo ordinal. Es más, si bien la oración en cuestión me resultó y me sigue resultando algo extraña, esta otra me suena aceptable, tal vez por la mayor unidad léxica que se produce entre "primer/a" y el sustantivo que sigue:

*Se terminó casando con la misma primera novia de su juventud.*

Answer (score 2):

También se puede usar con sustantivos, sobre todo en modo superlativo:

> «El mismísimo Juan Pablo II bendijo esta estola.»
>
> «A la inauguración vinieron todos los concejales y hasta el mismo alcalde.»
>
> «Tu padre mismo está de acuerdo con la decisión.»

En el ejemplo que planteas, «mismo» cualifica a «primer día» como grupo, que funciona como sustantivo. Es como si dijeran «la misma víspera» para referirse al día anterior, solo que no hay una palabra similar para «día primero».

Resumiendo: no veo un uso erróneo, si interpretas que cualifica a «día» o a «primer día», no a «primer» solamente.

Comment: Tanto en la gramática como en el diccionario de la RAE aparece "mismo" como adjetivo que califica a sustantivos. Lo que no aparece es su uso como adverbio.

Answer (score 0):

ESCRIBISTE:

> "Que tristeza terminar un *Tour* el *mismo* primer día"

*Mismo/misma* pueden reemplazarse por:

- *justo*
- *tan sólo siendo*
- *apenas siendo*
- *con tan sólo su*
- *y apenas empezando*
- *y eso que apenas empezaba/comenzaba*

P.D.

*Tour d' France* es un anglicismo/americanismo que viene de un francofonismo se usa *Carrera a Francia*. La razón por la que no se dice *vuelta* es porque sería una transliteración del francés y no una traducción. Lo mismo se da con *giro* es palabra italiana en la traducción del título. En ambos casos se dice *carrera*.

Comment: Hola Dario y gracias por la respuesta. Nótese que el significado y las alternativas los conozco. Mi duda iba destinada a conocer si es gramáticalmente correcto el uso de _mismo_ en este caso.

Comment: En cuanto al nombre... es complicado. Se trata de un producto comercial de nombre oficial "Tour de France" y en español todo el mundo (prensa, aficionados) usamos "Tour de Francia", igual que hablamos del "Giro de Italia". En cuanto al uso de la preposición, lo debatimos en [Why is the cycle race called La Vuelta “a” España, not “de”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17809/1674). Creo que _Vuelta a Francia_ tendría más sentido, pues _Carrera a Francia_ parecería una carrera cuyo destino final es Francia saliendo desde otro país.

Comment: Darío, podrías explicar un poco mejor/más por qué y en qué contextos mismo/a se puede sustituir por las opciones que propones? Esta respuesta ganaría mucho. Has visto por cierto la sección [answer]?